# read excel file with aspose version 2.5

Tags: aspose, aspose-cells

I want to read excel file with aspose version 2.5, I know that in the latest version we can do this like : 

`Workbook w = new Workbook(fileStream);
Cells cells = w.getWorksheets().get(0).getCells();`

I didn't found any documentation on aspose 2.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the following sample code and its sample console output. The code reads the source excel file and prints the names of cells A1 to A10 and its values.

**Java**

```
// Open the workbook with inputstream or filepath
Workbook wb = new Workbook();
wb.open("source.xlsx");

// Access first worksheet
Worksheet ws = wb.getWorksheets().getSheet(0);

// Read cells A1 to A10 and print their values
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int row = i;
    int col = 0;

    // Access the cell by row and col indices
    Cell cell = ws.getCells().getCell(row, col);

    // Print cell name and its value
    System.out.println(cell.getName() + ": " + cell.getStringValue());
}
```

**Sample Console Output**

```
A1: 13
A2: 16
A3: 87
A4: 73
A5: 69
A6: 91
A7: 59
A8: 46
A9: 82
A10: 54
```

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose